How to resolve 'null' output in terminal when fetching data in Flutter?
I'm following a Flutter tutorial on YouTube to fetch data from a backend. Despite following the tutorial steps, I'm unable to retrieve data as expected.
After contacting the tutorial creator, I was advised to check the response status code when fetching data. The code correctly prints the status code, but the data fetching itself seems to fail, resulting in a null output in the terminal. Here's how I modified the debugging step:
print(response.statusCode.toString());

This change replaced the previous debugging message:
print("we did not get any data");

Code:
// File: data_controller.dart
import 'package:flutter_golang_yt/services/service.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DataController extends GetxController{
  DataService service = DataService();

  Future<void> getData() async {
    Response response = await service.getData();
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      print("we got the data: ${response.body}");
    } else {
      print("Failed to fetch data: Status code ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }
}

// File: services.dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DataService extends GetConnect {
  Future<Response> getData() async {
    return await get("http://localhost:3306/gettasks");
  }
}


I have removed unnecessary details to focus on the main issue, which is data fetching. This code should be directly runnable and sufficient to reproduce the issue.
Output
The terminal outputs the following:
[GETX] Instance "DataController" has been initialized
I/flutter (15548): null


I’m voting to close this question because you already asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72218815/

Can you help me?

Does this answer your question? Error: I/flutter (15548): null on terminal

I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I'm able to deleted 5 posts per 24 hours, that's why I can't delete it right now
